# width: 100% съедает margin между блоками

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть flex-контейнер. В нём четыре кнопки, они должны занимать 100% экрана. Между кнопками есть небольшой отступ в один пиксель. Для красоты. Но есть проблема: кнопки находятся внутри своих div-блоков, а эти div-блоки уже внутри flex-контейнера. Мы задали ширину для div, но не для кнопки и потому её размер минимально возможный.

Для решения этой проблемы я нашёл два способа:

- Превратить div-блоки тоже в flex-контейнер с одним элементом и задать кнопке `flex: 1 0 auto;`
- Задать для кнопки `width: 100%`

Оба способа работают, но во втором отступ между кнопками пропадает. Почему?

Да, я уже понял свою ошибку, надо было `margin` ставить для div-блоков, а не самих кнопок. Но я всё ещё не понимаю, почему этот margin исчезает.

```css
/* Основной стиль */

.html, .body, .container {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}

.button-container {
  width: 25%;
}

.button-container button {
  /* Тот самый пробел между кнопками */
  margin: 0 1px 0 0;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: 0;
}

.button-container:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

/* Первый способ расширить кнопку */
/*
.button-container {
  display: flex;
}

.button-container button {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
*/

/* Второй способ расширить кнопку */
.button-container button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button-container"><button>1</button></div>
  <div class="button-container"><button>2</button></div>
  <div class="button-container"><button>3</button></div>
  <div class="button-container"><button>4</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Маргин никуда не исчезает, он просто торчит в соседнюю кнопку. Ну а так как ширина div'ов строго определена (25% плюс flex), то этот маргин ни на что не влияет. Если хочется сделать промежуток через width, то нужно писать что-то вроде `width: calc(100% - 1px)`

Comment: @andreymal Понял проблему. Странно, в моём понимании, в таком случае должно было произойти хоть что-нибудь. Например, переполнение за границы экрана и возникновение горизонтальной прокрутки.

Comment: Если добавить маргина побольше (от 9 пикселей), то маргин самой последней кнопки начнёт торчать за край страницы и прокрутка таки появится

Comment: @andreymal А какой способ принято использовать и в каком случае? Как я понимаю, всё-таки в этой ситуации более "чистым" будет способ через `flex`. Но не везде ведь его пихать, инструмент надо подбирать под ситуацию.

Comment: Почему бы и не через flex, если убрать `width:25%` и прописать `flex-grow: 1; margin-right: 1px;` то вроде похоже на желаемое

Comment: @andreymal Ага. Значит делаю вывод: по возможности, без веской причины, разные подходы лучше не мешать. В данном случае `flexbox` давал все инструменты для удобного решения поставленной задачи. Спасибо, разобрался!

Comment: @andreymal А вообще, нет. Если использовать вместо `width: 25%` `flex-grow: 1;`, то всё работает, но когда таких рядков с кнопками много, они становятся немного кривыми из-за разного размера кнопок в разных рядах. [Скриншот.](http://pics.rsh.ru/img/Untitled_xuj1pjgi.png) Это к изначальному вопросу уже не совсем относится но, получается, в такой ситуации никакого другого выбора кроме `width` нет?

Comment: Ага, я забыл, что ширина считается по контенту. Вроде можно совместить с `flex-basis: 25%` или тем же `width: 25%` чтобы было одинаково

Comment: @andreymal Теперь, кажется, всё понятно.